# Array formula for adding letters after duplicate numbers in order

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

The below formula adds a letter after a sequential number, A, B, C, D, etc for the same number until it finds a new number, then it starts again from A.

I need help on turning this into an array formula, if possible?

```
=J3&CHAR(96+COUNTIF(J$3:J3,J3))
```

I tried it this way, and depending on if I amend J3:J3, I get either A or D at end of the number?

```
={"";arrayformula(J3:J&CHAR(96+COUNTIF(J$3:J,J3:J)))}
```

The formula as a single line pushes out the below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(A1:A&LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, 
 ROW(A2:A)-MATCH(A1:A, A1:A, 0), 4), 1, ))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi User0, thanks, that works a charm. :)